# Laravel 5.5 not reading config arrays from .env file

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.5

Trying to read an array from .env file, which has a value with a comma separated string, as shown below. I want to also trim spaces and remove empty values. I used array_filter( array_map('trim', array))), but I couldn't even get past explode().

```
//.env file

ALLOWED_ORIGINS="http://localhost, http://mydomain.dev,http:mydomain.dev:4000"
```

Here is the cors.php

```
//cors.php file

[    
'allowedOrigins' => explode(",", env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS')),   
],
```

Ideally, I would like to trim and remove empty values, as shown below, but I had to comment out that code, just to get past explode()

```
'allowedOrigins' => array_filter( array_map('trim', 
                                explode(",", env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS'))
                                ))
```

Comment: php artisan config:clear

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I get an error The HTTP status code "22007" is not valid. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):
The stack trace goes into Laravel files, but points to an issue with arrays.

Comment: @Les I don't think it's related to the `.env` file and configs. You should show the full error message and related code.

Comment: I get the following error:

[2018-01-12 01:01:13] local.ERROR: The HTTP status code "22007" is not valid. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The HTTP status code \"22007\" is not valid. at /myproject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:461)
[stacktrace]
#0 /myproject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(201): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->setStatusCode(22007)
#1 /myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(55): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Array, '22007', Array)
.....

Comment: Grep for `22007` in your code.

Comment: I did that already, by the way. Thank you all. Let me dig this a little deeper. I inherited the code :( and it's been hectic finding my way around it. Looks like the 22007 is a mysql error so it was probably thrown with the exception without a proper message.

Comment: Isn't `http:mydomain.dev:4000` an error ? Your code doing the `array_filter...` is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, that was me incorrectly anonymizing the host names. Actual one in my .env is correct. Will fix it for the next person who references this.

Comment: That you all. Update. I found the issue, but still don't have a solution. I'll post it in a different question since issue is not related to the configs. I'm a Laravel + php noob, please bare with me. 
The issue was happening at login, when deleting the the access and refresh tokens. Eloquent throws an exception during refresh_token_model->delete(). Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:).